# Gmail add spaces in link href attribute

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

Using PHPMailer to send an email, when I view the email in Gmail in the href attribute of the link is displayed a space (%20). For example:

http://www.domain.it/page.php?u%20tente=5691457&annuncio=54ad79ccc9&codice=1457

HTML code that is passed to PHPMailer does not contain space.

Comment: You need to show your code, and your data.

Answer (score 0):

I add this problem today. I had a link that was more than 998 octets long and the SMTP server splitted it.

Check that the header of your email Content-Transfer-Encoding is set to something different than 7bit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding